# Groovy method print intercepts Joda date print

Tags: java, groovy, jodatime, spock

I am writing a spock test and I need to get a string to give my method an input

```
DateTimeFormatter yyyyMMddFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
yyyyMMddFormatter.print(fromDate)
```

The Groovy's print method is being called instead of joda datetimeformatter's print method. How can I call the original method instead of Groovy method?

Comment: what type is `fromDate`?

Answer (score 0):

without seeing how `fromDate` is assigned, my guess is that `fromDate`'s type does not match any of the signatures of the `print` method in `DateTimeFormatter`.  So the Groovy default method executes instead.